# When exactly should I ask questions in SO?

Tags: discussion

I am newbie to SO and programming.I am pretty confused about asking questions because I see people downvoting for asking basic questions and some calling help vampires.

I would like to know in which of these 2 situations must I come to SO for help

**Situation 1**

Research on Google, practice and then ask, What if I am newbie to programming and facing difficulty in understanding the official documentation

**Question**: Should I ask in SO or not ??

**Situation 2**

Trying solving yourself and search in SO, still I do not understand the questions.

**Question**: Should I ask in SO or not ??

Or are there any other situations in which I must not ask in SO or any thing that can help me understand.

Before asking this question I read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but still in confusion.

Comment: In the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) `Search, and research`, in this case `What if I am newbie to programming and facing difficulty in understanding the official documentation ?`

Comment: SO is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Such posters are expected to have a level of understanding of the languages etc. that they tag.  If they do not, they will probably not understand the answers and that results in a continual back-and-forth thread of misery and/or downvoting.   SO does not provide free tuition, either in programming or understanding documentation.

Comment: @MartinJames  `SO does not provide free tuition, either in programming or understanding documentation`, What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity) then ?.. I can point out many like these.

Comment: It's from five years ago.  Since then, the level of trash has become a deluge and posters are now, unfortunately, stuck with contributors with very little tolerance for bad questions.  Note that even a newb can post a good question - it does happen, and usually gets a good answer.  OTOH, questions that can be answered by googling the title with 20,000,000 results are typically downCloseVoted into oblivion.

Comment: Related: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: @MartinJames `SO does not provide free tuition, either in programming or understanding documentation` then what would you ask in SO ?? Bug reports ??  So my guess is that only geniuses should ask in SO ?? Every one is not everyone if you would see `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers` . It is a free community , the only rules here are to avoid asking low quality questions. You are totally wrong.Please do read the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) once again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions are mostly down-voted when they do not show sufficient research.

**Situation 1**:  If you have gone through the documentation and are unable to understand, there is a chance that someone else has already raised that issue on SO. There are also many blogs and tutorials to help you get started, especially for popular languages. Refer to them. If all else fails, link the documentation (or other tutorials) to your question, and mention the exact lines that you are having trouble comprehending.

**Situation 2**: You are always expected to try to solve yourself and search SO before asking. If you're a beginner in a particular language, there is a *very* high chance that a similar question already exists. If you find a similar but slightly different question, include a link to that question and explain how yours is different.

***Always*** include the code that you've already tried. Although SO may seem unwelcoming to new users, in my experience, if you show adequate research, you will most likely get a good answer.

**Edit (based on comments):** Each of your questions should be self-contained. No-one would like to click a link and read your previous question to understand the background. Include all necessary information and code with each question. What I meant with `include a link to that question and explain how yours is different` was that you have to make people understand that you have already tried A, B and C as mentioned in this similar question, but none of them seem to solve your problem.

Comment: `link the documentation (or other tutorials) to your question,` +1 for this and `include a link to that question and explain how yours is different.`. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @ ujwal - `include a link to that question and explain how yours is different` will people read that question, Some people have said `No one has the time to read your previous question, Just post the code where you are having the problem ` In such cases what do I do ?

Comment: @IllegalPointerException Well, a question has to be **self-contained**. But you need to clearly demonstrate what your problem is, and how much (if at all) any answer must repeat the basics for you (If it is *too much*, your question is *too broad*). The latter part is facilitated by linking other tries to explain your problem / similar questions which *just* miss answering your point, and clearly and concisely explaining their shortcomings for your case.

Comment: @IllegalPointerException please look at the edit above.

Comment: @Ujjwal Thanks a lot for the explanation. Now I understand very well.

Comment: SO is really unfriendly to new users, and sometimes, not-so-new users.  People down-vote without even saying why ....

Comment: @JosephDoggie `SO is really unfriendly to new users` You are wrong,How do you say that ? Downvotes ???

Comment: instead of getting their questions answered in a straight-forward manner, many new users face a lot of rules, which site it belongs on, noting there already is an answer on such and such a page, etc.

Comment: People downvote without saying why because they would rather spend their time answering good questions than waste it explaining bad ones.  If new users click through the tour without reading anything, then they are highly likely to post inappropriate, off-topic or plain bad questions.  They then get downvoted out-of-hand.

Comment: @JosephDoggie as an example, one user recently posted on meta about the etiquette of explaining downvotes.  There are already dozens of meta posts re. this subject, and one set of bad questions is from posters who do not search for duplicates before posting.  They are often anonymously downvoted.

Comment: @JosephDoggie New users must go through the help center before asking questions that is why there is help center and still if it does not help then Meta is only the last option.